# Titanium gives error: Specified Provisioning Profile is invalid or is the wrong type

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I can't get Titanium to accept my provisioning profile.

I am using Titanium to build a development app to run on my iPhone and that of two others. I have created the certificates, app ids, and provisioning profiles but when I come to create a package for distributing via iTune I get the error:

"Specified Provisioning Profile is invalid or is the wrong type"

I have tried pretty much every option I can think with respect to ways to build the package and types of provisioning profiles but it consistently fails with this message.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always get xCode to build correctly first. I set up a blank helloWorld application in xCode and follow the Apple guide there on their resources site. Once this is set up titanium will pick up on your valid certificate and provisioning profiles.

Check that when you are trying to run the project you have removed any invalid or old provisioning profiles. This can be done under xCode device manager > Selected device , click the settings wheel in the bottom left > Show provisioning profiles... You'll then see a list of profiles you re trying to build with, if you've created a couple that have the same name it could be selecting the wrong one.